# OpenCV (C++) matrix release not working as expected?

Tags: c++, opencv

According to [OpenCV Intro Doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html#automatic-memory-management), code that I wrote below should result in `im` being frame 2 and `imPrev` frame 1; however, they are both frame 2. Why and what is a simple and efficient fix?

```
Mat im, imPrev;
VideoCapture v(fileName);

v >> im;           // im = frame1
imPrev = im;       // im = imPrev = frame1
im.release();      // im = empty, imPrev = frame1
v >> im;           // I wanted      im = frame2, imPrev = frame1
                   // but it became im = imPrev = frame2
```

(OpenCV 2.4.5)

Note: The last three lines go in a loop so I'd preferably like to avoid unnecessary memory allocation on every iteration (eg. using `clone`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you do like:

v >> im;

you get an img, that points to static memory inside the webcam driver.

it is not refcounted, so your im.release() has no effect at all.

## -------------

but the problem is here:

```
imPrev = im;   
// this is a shallow copy only, the Mat struct gets copied, the pixels are shared.
```

replace it with:

```
imPrev = im.clone(); // imPrev now owns it own pixels
```

## --------------

[edit]

imho, you also don't want 2 >> or read operations per loop, so maybe make it :

```
Mat cur,prev;
while(1)
{
   capture >> cur;
   if ( ! prev.empty() )
   {
        process(cur,prev);
   }
   prev = cur.clone();
}
```

Comment: I don't seem to be able to find in the documentation that matrices obtained from `v >> im` behave differently (ie stay intact) than normally allocated ones. You seem to be right but how do you know? Is there anywhere I can read more about this?

Comment: see the [note here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-read)